# Adding jquery into symfony project without encore

Tags: jquery, symfony, webpack-encore

I want to add jquery to my project to customize CollectionType in my form. As far as I know easiest way to include jquery is to use webpack/encore but I just need jquery for this specific thing, nothing more. So are there any good ways to include jquery without installing whole encore?

Comment: You can add it to your base template like you would any normal HTML file. Like this for example with a CDN `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>`..

Answer (score 0):

well the easiest way should be to put the js file in the public web folder

and in your template you just load it from there, i.e

```
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
```